# How to sort N lists by the total sum of elements of each list with Mathematica?

Tags: list, wolfram-mathematica, sorting, mathematica-8

Given a list containing `k` sublists, let
`A={{a1,a2,a3,...},{b1,b2,b3,...},...}`, I want to sort those sublists by their `Total[A[i]]`. Is there any efficient way to make this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that in many cases, sorting based on `Ordering` can be faster than `SortBy`, because it allows us to leverage vectorization. In this particular case, the speed-up is not that huge:

```
In[50]:= test = RandomInteger[10,{5000000,5}];

In[54]:= (res1=SortBy[test,{Total}]);//Timing
(res2 = test[[Ordering[Total[test,{2}]]]]);//Timing
res1===res2

Out[54]= {1.422,Null}
Out[55]= {1.125,Null}
Out[56]= True
```

But, this is because `Total` is a built-in function. The whole reason why `SortBy` was introduced, is efficiency (that is, for a single comparison function. For several comparison functions as tie-breakers, also convenience). It is more efficient that `Sort`, because it is more specific, and therefore by-passes more steps in the main evaluation sequence. However, there is no way for `SortBy` to leverage the possible listability (vectorized nature) of the function on which the sorting is based - it is applied to list elements one-by-one. The solution with ordering does explicitly leverage the possibility of whole-sale computation of the sorting function (in this case, `Total[#,{2}]&` does this), and therefore is faster.

If, for example, the task would be to sort according to a total of the second, third and fourth element in each sublist, we'd see a larger performance difference:

```
In[60]:= (res3=SortBy[test,{Total[#[[2;;4]]]&}]);//Timing
(res4=test[[Ordering[Total[test[[All,2;;4]],{2}]]]]);//Timing
res3==res4

Out[60]= {2.39,Null}
Out[61]= {1.11,Null}
Out[62]= True
```

Generally, the performance boost will be the largest for sorting functions which are both computationally intensive and vectorized, and such that they are much faster when applied to the whole list. Note, however, that the performance boost for sorting will never be as large as for the sorting function itself, for large lists.  This is because of the intrinsic complexity of sorting, which is proportional to `n*Log[n]` for large lists of length `n`, and this complexity will always be there.

Answer (score 9):

Check `SortBy` in documentation for a range of possibilities to sort lists of lists.

```
 SortBy[A,Total]
```

gives what you need.

EDIT: Per Mr. Wizard's comment below and the explanation in the link therein,

```
SortBy[A,{Total}]
```

is better.

Comment: @Mr Wizard commented the other day about another sorting problem and it seems that `SortBy[A, {Total}]` would be slightly faster for this.

Comment: Thank you @Mike. Very interesting; it sounds like a vintage Mr.Wizard discovery. Do you remember the question or the link?

Comment: not offhand other than it was in the last 3-4 days and a question related to sorting. Have to go now otherwise I would look for it.

Comment: @kguler it is not my discovery; it produces a stable sort without tie-breaking, as [explained by Andrew Moylan](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3332690/618728).  It logically follows that if there are a lot of ties this will be faster.  It also changes the result that you get, so please be aware of what you are doing.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, thank you so much for the link. I did notice the results changing and puzzled by it; now it makes sense.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: Of course the fastest sort would be a non-stable sort without tie-breaking (i.e. you don't care which order equivalent elements have). Does Mathematica offer that one, too?

Comment: @celtschk, do you mean for `Sort`, or for `SortBy`?

Answer (score 0):

The following should work (but I can't test it right now):

```
Sort[A, Total[#1]<Total[#2]&]
```